# Node.JS & ExpressJS / Make a difference between Host Name and IP Address

Tags: node.js, express

I am logging to an express sesssion in two ways

1. `http://myhostname.com/login`
2. `http://123.123.43.12/login`

Ip adress of `myhostname.com` is `123.123.43.12`.

To check if someone is already logging, I basically do for this example

> if (user === req.session.username && pwd === req.session.password)

Then I make the same AJAX inquiry from a page

1. In `http://myhostname.com/main.html` , AJAX inquiry to `http://123.123.43.12/ajax` => Error not logging
2. In `http://123.123.43.12/main.html`, AJAX inquiry to `http://123.123.43.12/ajax` => Success

How can I tell expressJS (session) or node that `myhostname.com` and `123.123.43.12` are identical ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). The rules for deciding if two urls are of same origin are strictly same protocol, host and port. myhostname.com and 123.123.43.12 are not of same origin by that.

AJAX follows same origin policy so it cannot inquiry any other page than its origin. Which is why if you access main from `123.123.43.12`, you can access its ajax, but not from `myhostname.com`. If you use `myhostname.com` stick to it, or if you use `123.123.43.12` then stick to that. Don't use both interchangeably.

Comment: Thanks. I will use JSONP technic instead.